# Simple interactive windows firewall

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

I'm surprised I cannot find any windows application fulfilling following requirements:

- to behave as standard, simple, standalone and interactive windows **firewall**, nothing more
- not to be unmanageable Microsoft half-Firewall
- to have easy manageable set of rules (allow/deny for application:address:port:protocol)
- to ask on any outgoing/incoming connection (not yet contained within the rule set)
- to allow creation of rule from the connection details
- to occupy single process (two processes at maximum, when the GUI is running)
- not to have any of `smart.*`, `anti.*`, `.*defense.*`, `.*cloud.*`, `.*online.*`, `.*hips.*` and similar "technologies" or "features"

Does still exist something like this? Just plain fast firewall?
I have tried several ones, the almost acceptables were:

- Comodo (being "internet security" is uselessly complicated, myriads of processes and features)
- ZoneAlarm (unable to stay in "manual" mode, disregarding the setup it still creates the rules by itself)

but unfortunately they also failed.

Comment: Windows Firewall supports all this *except* block notification, one of its few downside. Forget about its control panel applet, the real management interface is **windows firewall with advanced security** (search in start menu and give it a try, it's much more powerful that what Microsoft frequently advertises).

Comment: im using windows firewall control (http://www.binisoft.org/wfc.php), even though it uses the stock firewall, it does fill every of your requirement except the standalone part. it does give users more power. currently trying out glasswire though since im hearing good things about it